# Resolve remote origin already exists error at Git lab Runner

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci-runner, cd

**My Error at git lab runner terminal**

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
warning: failed to remove code/ecom_front_proj/dist/sections: Permission denied
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I am trying to deploy my project to an AWS server by git runner using CI CD. First time the code deploys successfully. If I commit a second time it shows the above error.

If I delete my runner and create new one it is deploying successfully.
I don't know how to delete the remote origin file that already exists.

My Git.yml

```
image: docker
> 
> services:
>   - docker:dind
> 
> stages:
>   - test
>   - deploy
> 
> test:   stage: test   only:
>     - master
>       script:
>     - echo run tests in this section
> 
> step-deploy-prod:   stage: deploy   only:
>     - master   script:
>    
>     - sudo docker system prune -f
>     - sudo docker volume prune -f
>     - sudo docker image prune -f
>     - sudo docker-compose build --no-cache
>     - sudo docker-compose up -d   environment: development
```

My Docker file

```
FROM node:6 LABEL Aathi <aathi@techardors.com>
> 
> RUN apk update && apk add git RUN apk add nodejs  RUN apk add nginx
> RUN set -x ; \   addgroup -g 82 -S www-data ; \   adduser -u 82 -D -S
> -G www-data www-data && exit 0 ; exit 1
> 
> COPY ./nginx.conf     /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
> #COPY ./localhost.crt /etc/nginx/localhost.crt
> #COPY ./localhost.key /etc/nginx/localhost.key COPY ./code/ecom_front_proj /sections WORKDIR sections RUN npm install RUN
> npm install -g @angular/cli RUN ng build --prod
```

My docker Compose File

```
version: '2'
> 
> services:   web:
>     container_name: nginx
>     build: .
>     ports:
>       - "4200:4200"
>     command: nginx -g "daemon off";
>     volumes:
>       - ./code/ecom_front_proj/dist/sections:/www:ro
```

My nginx file

```
user www-data; worker_processes 1; pid /run/nginx.pid;
> 
> events {  worker_connections 768;     # multi_accept on; }
> 
> http {    sendfile off;   tcp_nopush on;  tcp_nodelay on;
>   keepalive_timeout 65;   types_hash_max_size 2048;
> 
>   include /etc/nginx/mime.types;  default_type
> application/octet-stream;
> 
>   #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;  #error_log
> /var/log/nginx/error.log;
> 
>   gzip on;    gzip_disable "msie6";
> 
>       server {        #listen 8443 ssl;       listen 4200;        #server_name 
> localhost;
> 
>       #ssl_certificate      localhost.crt;        #ssl_certificate_key 
> localhost.key;
> 
>       location / {
>             root  /sections/dist/sections;
>             index index.html;
>          }
>       
>       } }
```

Comment: i have given access to my git runner                                                                            sudo usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner
sudo nano /etc/sudoers

gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL                                                                           added this line in my sudoers

Comment: which git-runner version is working fine and can any one give me a link for installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you run `gitlab-runner` version 11.9.0 and it has a [bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4080).

Alternatively, your `gitlab-runner` was installed with privileges that not allow it to change file structure in the mentioned path, consider [reinstalling](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/) or adding these privileges.